# data structure - how to implement hash tables (including association lists) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable

I am working on a hash table /data structure exercise but dont understand it quite well.
Each data has to be an instance of the list 'List' and using athe hash function, I need to add key /value pairs to the correct list and return the items based on their key.
As what I tried so far doesnt work, any help or explanation why what I have so far doesnt work would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
function List () {
  this.head=null;
}
function ListN (key, value, next) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
  this.next = next;
}
List.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
 var newNode=new ListN(key, value, this.head);
  this.head=newNode;
};

List.prototype.get = function (key) {
  var node = this.head;
    while (node) {
       if (node.key === key) {
        return node.value;
       }
        node = node.next;
    }
};
  smallList = new List();

function HashT () {
  this.data = Array(30);
}

HashT.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
  var index=hash(key);
  if (!this.data[index]) {
    this.data[index]=new List();
  }

  this.data[index].set({key:key, value:value});
};

HashT.prototype.get = function (key) {
var index=hash(key);
return this.data[index];

};
```

Comment: Just be careful no one inputs the key `NaN`

Comment: In any non-stupid ECMAScript implementation, the underlying data structure of an object is a hash. So just use a plain object. Or a map, if the keys might not be strings.

Comment: @Oriol I think the point of the exercise is to learn how hash tables are implemented. Using an object for it would be like teaching someone how to build a birdhouse by telling them to go to a pet store and buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, your mistake is here:

```
this.data[index].set({key:key, value:value});
```

It needs to be changed to

```
this.data[index].set(key, value);
```

In your `HashT.prototype.get`, the `return` statement needs to be:

```
return this.data[index].get(key);
```

Comment: Thank you! Also how can I return only the one that matches the key? I tried if (this.data.key===key){
  return this.data[index];
} but it doesn't work

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you explain it and also why that what I had wouldn't work as Im trying to understand hash tables